# Can Graphviz render State Transition Diagrams like this?

Tags: state, diagram, graphviz

Can Graphviz render State Transition Diagrams exactly like this?

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cf/Finite_state_machine_example_with_comments.svg

=== Edit ===

Marapet's code comes really close (see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IorMH.png ). I am accepting his answer.

Comment: It's certainly a popular tool for drawing automata diagrams, but if it can draw that exact picture, I'm not sure. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: It's not about getting the same picture but the same diagram type (that is with support for the transition conditions, entry actions etc. in a similar layout/appearance). I haven't tried it yet, I was wondering if someone already figured out how to render STDs similar to this.

Comment: Yes, I've done this on several occasions. It's pretty simple.

Comment: Do you have an example that accomplishes this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd create nodes for the *transition conditions* :

```
digraph g{
  Opened[label="1\nOpened\nE: open door"];
  Closed[label="2\nClosed\nE: closed door"];
  node[shape=plaintext];

  Opened -> close_door[arrowhead=none];
  close_door -> Closed;
  Opened -> open_door[dir=back];
  open_door -> Closed[arrowhead=none];
}
```

Comment: I'm glad it helps! ... maybe also use html-like label for the _Opened_ and _Closed_ nodes to use bold text, as well as use a monospace font for the _transition condition_ nodes.

Answer (score 2):

I would use label on the arrow instead of creating a node for the close_door:

Opened -> Closed [label=close_door];